# Performselector - argument 2 makes pointer from integer without cast

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performselector

I have this code:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animationWithType:) withObject:PasscodeAnimationTypeConfirm afterDelay:0.2];
```

To this method:

```
-(void)animationWithType:(PasscodeAnimationType)type;
```

Putting this in it's place:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animationWithType:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:PasscodeAnimationTypeConfirm] afterDelay:0.2];
```

returns an NSLog of "1", which my method doesn't class as the same value as PasscodeAnimationTypeConfirm. How can i fix this?

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but naming conventions suggest animationWithType: will return an animation of given type. I suggest you change it to performAnimationWithType: instead.

Comment: I've been busily removing as many instances of performSelector as I can and replacing them with blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, as far as I know, you can only do performSelector:blahBlah:withDelay: with objects as parameters, not types (ints, chars, etc.).

You can create another function to help you, like this:

```
-(void)animationWithNumber:(NSNumber)type{
    [self animationWithType:[NSNumber intValue]];
}
```

And using this one from the code you posted:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animationWithType:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:PasscodeAnimationTypeConfirm] afterDelay:0.2];
```

Comment: A better way to do this would be with NSInvocation, as you don't need to create a new method, just for this case.

Answer (score 1):

@Emilio: Shouldn't your performSelector call invoke your new method?

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animationWithNumber:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:PasscodeAnimationTypeConfirm] afterDelay:0.2];
```

Here is an example of mine showing a more detailed use of this concept.

http://kerkermeister.net/objective-c-adapter-from-nsinteger-to-id-when-using-performselector-withobject/

The adapter looks like this and performs some more checks:

```
-(void)animationWithNumber:(id)_animationType {
    if ([_animationType respondsToSelector:@selector(intValue)]) {
        int _t = [_animationType intValue];
        switch (_t) {
            case AnimationType1:
                _t = AnimationType1;
                break;
            case AnimationType2:
                _t = AnimationType2;
                break;
            default:
                _t = AnimationTypeUndefined;
                break;
        }
        [self animationWithType:_t];
    }
}
```